# Show that a unit is a divisor of every other element in an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have an integral domain $(R,+,\cdot)$ and I need to show that $x \in R$ is a unit iff it is a divisor of every $a \in R$.

As I just began to study integral domains I do not really know where to start. Do you have any tips?

Comment: If $x\in R^*$ and $a\in R$, then $a=x(x^{-1}a)$. If $x\in R$ is a divisor of every element, then in particular is a divisor of $1$. Then there is $y$ such that $1=xy$. So, $x\in R^*$

Comment: Check what you have written.  It does not match the title.  You are wishing to prove that $x$ is an element of the integral domain iff it is a divisor of every $a$?  Or you are wishing to prove that $x$ is a unit iff it is a divisor of every $a$?

Comment: Sorry you are right, I edited the question.

Comment: Units $u$ are the divisors of $1$. So $u\mid 1\mid r\Rightarrow u\mid r$ for all $r\in R$ by transitivity of divides (cf. linked dupe). Conversely $u$ divides all $r \Rightarrow u\mid 1\Rightarrow u$ a unit.

Answer (score 0):

The term “divisor” leads to thinking in terms of multiplication inverse.
$$d\ne 0:\frac{a}{d}=a \Leftrightarrow a\cdot \frac{1}{d}=a\Leftrightarrow a\cdot (d)^{-1}=a\Leftrightarrow (d)^{-1}=1\Leftrightarrow d=1^{-1}=1(\therefore)$$